# Roled Based Access Control Model

Tags: spring-security

I'm a fresher in building security problems. Now I am developing a project based on RBAC model,and I choose Spring Security 3 to implement it.

It's known that every role has its permissions in RBAC,and the way to judge whether a user has right to execute the operation is to obtain his roles first, and then fetch every permissions that the role has.I think permissions decide the right to operate the service layer(J2EE).

Spring Security provides annotations or Aspect to protect the service layer. But they're all based on role-leveled such as "hasRole". It seems this cut the relationship between the role and the permission so that it's not flexible to let the administer to distribute the permission.

What is the common way to solve this problem? Does Spring Security enable permission-protected implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two options:

- Role hierarchy
- ACL module

You can use [role hierarchy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/authz-arch.html#authz-hierarchical-roles) concept to achieve the same effect. In this case on Spring Security level both roles and permissions will be represented as roles.

There are true permissions in [ACL module](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#domain-acls). But they are used normally to prevent access to some domain object instance and not to prevent access to some service. So I think it is not what you want.